# Native "playlist" shortcode random playing... How?

Tags: shortcode

I'm using the beautiful shortcode "playlist" in my site but I want the random playing of my audio files.

What I use is this:

> [playlist tracklist="false" images="false" artists="false"
>   ids="7691,7690,7688,7687,7686,7685,7684,7683,7682,7681,7680,7679,7678,7677,7676,7674,3978,3647,3408,1395,1217,1216,1214,1213,1211,1210,1209,1208,1207,1206,1181,975,899,668,663,642,641"]

How to make random playing, maybe also with dad jQuery?

Comment: **Note for readers of this question:** There's a patch waiting for WP 4.1. Codex has been updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed all that duplicated and unnecessary stuff, take a look at otto's or kaiser's answers for the very simple solution.

- [Trac ticket: #29629](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29629).
- Codex entry for [Playlist Shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Playlist_Shortcode).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there is a both a bug and that the documentation was written incorrectly in the core code. However, there is a workaround that should work for the future and for any fixes that may be made to core.

It's a simple one too:

Use orderby="rand" in the shortcode.

Just that easy.

`[playlist orderby="rand" tracklist="false" images="false" artists="false" ids="7691,7690,7688,7687,7686,7685,7684,7683,7682,7681,7680,7679,7678,7677,7676,7674,3978,3647,3408,1395,1217,1216,1214,1213,1211,1210,1209,1208,1207,1206,1181,975,899,668,663,642,641"]`

Comment: That's what I've written in my answer. ;) Extended Codex with it now.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a shuffle

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {
?>
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    var playlist = $('.wp-playlist'); // Tune this if more than one.
    var tracks = $('.wp-playlist-tracks .wp-playlist-item', playlist);
    var last_shuffle = -1;
    var shuffle = function () {
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * tracks.length);
        if (i == last_shuffle) i = (i + 1) % tracks.length;
        last_shuffle = i;
        tracks.get(i).click();
    };
    shuffle();
    $('.mejs-mediaelement audio', playlist).on('ended', function (event) {
        shuffle();
    });
});
</script>
<?php
});
```

Answer (score 3):

### *Random* order

From what I can read in source, there's one argument responsible for this:

```
'order' => 'RAND',
```

In the case you use this, the `orderby` value will be set to `none`.

#### Edit

Ok, core code tells that this should work:

```
if ( 'RAND' == $atts['order'] ) {
    $atts['orderby'] = 'none';
}
```

But this is **not true**. In fact, you have to set the **`orderby`** value to `rand`, as the shortcode calls `get_posts()` and this is what returns posts in random order. In short: What core does with `RAND` is (afaik) completely unnecessary (and confusing).

### Default and always set arguments

If you want to filter the shortcode attributes for *all* `playlist` shortcode calls, then go with the following:

```
add_action( 'shortcode_atts_playlist', function( $output, $defaults, $custom )
{
    // do some array_merge() or wp_parse_args() here
    return $output;
}, 10, 3 );
```

### Custom override

If you want to override the `playlist` shortcode with a completely custom shortcode, go with shortcircuiting it - return the first argument of the following filter as *anything*, but not an empty string:

```
add_filter( 'post_playlist', function( $playlist = '', $attr )
{
    return $playlist;
}, 10, 2 );
```

### Debugging shortcodes

If you hit a wall and some argument isn't working, then it's probably a plugins or themes fault. Take a look at [`shortcode_atts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/shortcode_atts/). Then dump the contents of the filter inside the callback I've shown above.

Comment: Too complicated. I just want to play random in my shortcode PLAYLIST.

Comment: _Too complicated_ ? Welcome to WordPress **Development**.